# How to transform this function based view to class based view?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have some function based view for chat that i want to transform to class based view

```
def ShowChatPage(request,room_name,person_name):
    return render(request,"chat_screen.html",{'room_name':room_name,'person_name':person_name})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple [**`TemplateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview):

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ShowChatPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'chat_screen.html'
```

Normally the *URL parameters* are already passed to the template as well, since the basic [**`get`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2c3497980f925abcee397a99fbfc535feee5d947/django/views/generic/base.py#L153-L159) is implemented as:

> ```
> class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):
>     """
>     Render a template. Pass keyword arguments from the URLconf to the context.
>     """
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
>         return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

Comment: don't forget to add the context :)

Comment: i know about that, but how to do context part like room_name and person_name?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: this is *passed* URL parameters are by default passed to the context.

Comment: @murad: you don't have to implement that, these *are* already passed to the template.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: see edit, the `TemplateView` thus calls `get_context_data` with `**kwargs` (the URL parameters), and these serve as an initial context. It will furthermore add a `view` to the context, etc. But the URL parameters *are* already in the context.

Comment: thanks, in a word i should just create template view and context data will be built-in by default?

Comment: @murad: yes, the url parameters are by default passed to the context data.